# Print list from different predicate in PROLOG

Tags: printing, prolog, predicate

I'm currently starting a new language (PROLOG) and I came across with a few issues.

I'm developing a simple board game in which I'm required to print the board. I've developed a *PrintBoard* and *initialBoard* predicate (as shown below), and I want to be able to run it from the *main* predicate, just like so:

```
printBoard([Head|Tail]) :- 
        printRow(Head),
        printBoard(Tail).
printBoard([]).

printRow([Head|Tail]) :-
        write(Head),
        write('  '),
        printRow(Tail).
printRow([]) :- nl.

initialBoard(Board) :- Board = ([
                                   ['b0','b0','b0','b0','b1'], 
                                   ['b0','b0','b0','b0','b0'], 
                                   ['b0','b0','b0','b0','b0'],
                                   ['b0','b0','b0','b0','b0'],
                                   ['b2','b0','b0','b0','b0']
                                ]).

main :- Board = initialBoard(Board), printBoard(Board).
```

By typing `main.` in the *SICStus PROLOG*, the program **should** output the following:

```
b0 b0 b0 b0 b1
b0 b0 b0 b0 b0
b0 b0 b0 b0 b0
b0 b0 b0 b0 b0
b2 b0 b0 b0 b0
```

But, instead, it returns **nothing**. (Returns `no`).

The only way it seems to work is by inserting the whole list all over again as the variable, just like so:

```
main :- printBoard(<insert whole list here>).
```

Even though I'm looking to run it as:

```
main :- printBoard(initialBoard(Board)).
```

The portion of code above works, if main is passed the *Board* argument, but is it possible without passing it?

Functional code:

```
main(Board) :- printBoard(initialBoard(Board)).
```

Comment: `printBoard(initialBoard)` should read `initialBoard(Board), printBoard(Board)`, in Prolog, `initialBoard` is a constant, its not the variable you expect it to be.

Comment: There was a type in that function, it was supposed to be printBoard(initialBoard(Board)).

Comment: No.  You misunderstand Prolog. `printBoard(Board)` expects a list! Thus: `main :- initialBoard(Board), printBoard(Board)`

Comment: ^That works, I don't know why I didn't try that out. Anyway, you might want to make an answer out of it so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: There's something I might have misunderstood.
Shouldn't initialBoard(Board) return a Board or does the predicate simply change the Board variable?

Comment: This is no surprise for Prolog beginners: In other languages you have interpreted function symbols. But in Prolog they remain what they are. Thus `?- X = 1+1.`  gives `X = 1+1` and not `2`. You need an extra built-in to get that, like `?- X is 1+1.`

Comment: There is no "returning" in Prolog. Both `Board = initialBoard(Board)` and `printBoard(initialBoard(Board))` are incorrect because you expect this. The only flow of information in Prolog is through named variables, there is no "evaluation" happening like you appear to expect with those two statements.